# How to find Pod which is using a PVC where storage name is specific Programatically in Go

Tags: go, kubernetes, csi-driver

I am looking to find pod in kubernetes which is using a PVC but we need to filter based on a specific storage class name

Eg:- PVC created using storageclass name "ABC"

Pod using that PVC

There are 100s of pods in all the namespace , i want to filter out only pod which is using PVC where storage class is ABC

Filtering is somehow not happening because Pod does not contain storage class information

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I don't think the Kubernetes REST API lets you search on arbitrary properties of objects; this might not be possible without iterating all the PVCs, then iterating all of the Pods.

Comment: first approach :- I tried fetching all the PVC's and from each of the PVC i compared the storageclass name . Storage class is hardcoded so i compare the storage class and find out PVC which is created using our CSI driver.  But now using PVC i was not able find the POD name . There is a field named Used By when we do describe PVC but using below code pvcList, err := clientSet.CoreV1().PersistentVolumeClaims("").List(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{}) we get the PVC details but not Used By field - which is the pod name which is using it

Comment: Second approach :- Fetch all the pods and iterate through each pod and see if has volume and volume.PersistentVolumeClaim . If it present i need to compare the storage class to know whether it is created through our CSI driver. There is no storage class field at pod level

Comment: The final goal is to find the pod which is using PVC which is created using our CSI driver. So that i can apply watch on that only